# Why doesn't Matlab `fopen` throw an exception?

Tags: matlab, file, exception, fopen

Why doesn't `fopen` throw an exception when the filename or path doesn't exist?

```
in_path = 'pqlcnaf8765mlr9f6lf2;

try
    in_file_id = fopen(in_path,'r');
catch 
    error('Problem with input file.')    
end
```

The `in_path` doesn't exist. The call returns `in_file_id` with the value of `-1`, but no exception is thrown. Does somebody know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not designed to throw an exception, as the documentation states:

```
If fopen cannot open the file, it returns -1.
```

You need to design your code to throw the exception that you want:

```
in_path = 'pqlcnaf8765mlr9f6lf2;

in_file_id = fopen(in_path,'r');
if in_file_id == -1
  error('Problem with input file.')    
end
```

**edit**

Re: The link in the 1st comment -> shows how to deal with a `try catch` block.  It is throwing an error because of the `fread` line.  You could do the same in your code:

```
try
  in_file_id = fopen(in_path,'r');
  fread(in_file_id);
catch 
  error('Problem with input file.')    
end
```

Having said that I don't think the link is a good example how to deal with a file not existing.

Comment: What about this link: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/respond-to-an-exception.html. This confused me (and still does). Thanks.

Comment: One more thing. How do I know if the function is designed to throw any errors? For example [audioinfo](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioinfo.html) throws, but where is this documented?

Comment: Most errors are runtime errors. Apart from this, many functions are written `C-style` where you get an error code. The functions are designed to throw only if input is wrong. There is not many explicit throws in MATLAB code. A full spec can be found in the doc.

Comment: So, `fread` throws, but `fopen` doesn't. :-/ And the documentation for this is still a mistery.

Comment: It is as @patrik says, `fopen` does not throw an error because the input is right. So you are not making an error programming side, but the file does not exist hence the C-style error (`-1`). The `fread` throws an error because giving it an input which is `-1` (not an integer) is a wrong input, thus an error programming side.

Comment: @NickyMattsson I agree this could be more concistent, but you will have to deal with it. The reason why they would do like this is reasonable still. Those coming from a C/C++ background would expect a function called `fopen` to return -1 if no file exists. This may also not be seen as an "exceptional situation" to all. However, it is not possible for `fread` to behave exactly as in C. MATLAB would have to return a valid output and this is not possible if the file is corrupted (of course you could return 0 or empty array if error though). Also file corruption is almost always "exceptional".